# Obtaining CPU thread usage in Java

Tags: java, benchmarking, cpu-usage

I have a question around getting CPU utilization for a given JNI block. I'm making some intensive CPU computation in the underlying C++ JNI native method. I'm in the process of optimizing this computation and want to benchmark it against varying inputs.

I need some guidance on how to go about measuring this. The alternatives I have considered so far are

- Using JMX `ThreadMXBean` to measure system CPU usage for the current thread that invokes call into JNI method. However, I am not sure if JNI code is executed within the invoking thread context. What happens when the thread spawns more threads?
- Using JMX `OperatingSystemMXBean` to get the CPU usage for the entire JVM. Ideally, this is not want I want as there could be parallel executions in JVM that might tweak the benchmarking.
- Measure externally using `getrusage(..)`. What I want to know here is that how is it different than using `OperatingSystemMXBean`.

Comment: ThreadMXBean#getCurrentThreadCpuTime() is fine for non-spawning JNI (if your Java/OS supports it). If it spanws you would have to dig deep into the system and cannot monitor it with Java means anymore. (yes I am basically agreeing with your fear :)

Comment: On Linux it uses either  [/proc/<pid>/cpu (slow)](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk6/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#4780) or [getcpu_clockid/clock_gettime](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/openjdk/jdk6/hotspot/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.cpp#1451) if supported. This is fast and high precision supported by pthreads.

Comment: If the operation is CPU-intensive, this means that what you want to measure is total running time, not ratio of CPU vs. I/O.  In this case, why is a simple "end time minus start time" measurement not good enough?  Sure, you will have greater accuracy if you exclude other threads, but on the other hand, it may be a big pain to exclude those threads, so is it worth the hassle?  Besides, one of these threads will be the GC, and if your java code is producing a lot of garbage, then this might be something you'd want to take into account and optimize too, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ThreadMXBean` to get cpu usage statistics from all running threads. In the example below the `CPU usage per thread` is calculated:

```
private int sampleTime = 10000;
private ThreadMXBean threadMxBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
private RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
private OperatingSystemMXBean osMxBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
private Map<Long, Long> threadInitialCPU = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
private Map<Long, Float> threadCPUUsage = new HashMap<Long, Float>();
private long initialUptime = runtimeMxBean.getUptime();

ThreadInfo[] threadInfos = threadMxBean.dumpAllThreads(false, false);
for (ThreadInfo info : threadInfos) {
    threadInitialCPU.put(info.getThreadId(), threadMxBean.getThreadCpuTime(info.getThreadId()));
}

try {Thread.sleep(sampleTime);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}

long upTime = runtimeMxBean.getUptime();

Map<Long, Long> threadCurrentCPU = new HashMap<Long, Long>();
ThreadInfo[] threadInfos = threadMxBean.dumpAllThreads(false, false);
for (ThreadInfo info : threadInfos) {
    threadCurrentCPU.put(info.getThreadId(), threadMxBean.getThreadCpuTime(info.getThreadId()));
}

// CPU over all processes
//int nrCPUs = osMxBean.getAvailableProcessors();
// total CPU: CPU % can be more than 100% (devided over multiple cpus)
long nrCPUs = 1;
// elapsedTime is in ms.
long elapsedTime = (upTime - initialUptime);
for (ThreadInfo info : threadInfos) {
    // elapsedCpu is in ns
    Long initialCPU = threadInitialCPU.get(info.getThreadId());
    if (initialCPU != null) {
        long elapsedCpu = threadCurrentCPU.get(info.getThreadId()) - initialCPU;
        float cpuUsage = elapsedCpu / (elapsedTime * 1000000F * nrCPUs);
        threadCPUUsage.put(info.getThreadId(), cpuUsage);
    }
}

// threadCPUUsage contains cpu % per thread
System.out.println(threadCPUUsage);
// You can use osMxBean.getThreadInfo(theadId) to get information on every thread reported in threadCPUUsage and analyze the most CPU intentive threads
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you save my day!

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, this method may help you:

- Run `kill -3 <pid of Java process>` to get the thread dump. Thread dump will be added standard output.
- Open the dump and search for the thread you're interested in. (You can search using class name)
- Get the thread PID (it's in hex) and convert it to decimal.
- Run `top` command.
- Press `Shift-H` to enable Threads View
- Identify the thread using decimal value you obtained above.
  You can see cpu / memory usage of your thread there.