# Core name, CPUUsage(%), MemoryUsage(%) in Java

Tags: java

How to get Core name, CPUUsage(%), MemoryUsage(%) in Java? Is there is any API to get this?

Comment: Use Process.exec to run a platform specific utility and scrape its output.  *"Is there is any api to get this"* - not a standard one.

Comment: What are "Core name,CPUUsage(%), MemoryUsage(%)" ?

Comment: Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
        int numberOfProcessors = runtime.availableProcessors();

I tried this and got 4 core. and I want to know that how can I get the all given detail .?... Jotik

Comment: @ArunGupta - See my comment above.

Comment: I am little bit week in programmin...I am not getting u.... @ Stephen

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931391/obtaining-cpu-thread-usage-in-java

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ProsessBuilder class to run commands and parse the values from the output of the command.

[ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)