# CPU ram and free space for remote servers java

Tags: java, cpu, ram

I want to get CPU ram free space with java for many server 
any idea.

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? I suggest you use a tool which does this for you already which you can research using google.

Comment: i tried  Process c = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commande); but i have system inf for my local machine i wich i have ram cpu for other server

Comment: i tried getTotalSpace() also but the result is for my local machine

Comment: also   Process process = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe","\\\\xxxxx", "systeminfo |find Available Physical Memory").start(); but without result

Comment: For CPU utilization, I've [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32890412/1183010) another question

Comment: Thanks R oosterholt but i want for remote server ????

Answer (score 1):

Well depending on target platform there are multiple ways:

- Have java clients running on each system that will collect this information on request and then have a server that collect and display all this information. This is most platform independent solution but require you to write client and server and install clients on each system.
- If SSH is supported on platforms, you can using Java program to login to each system and use command line utilities to query resource. This however require you to either have credentials for each system or the SSH keys available.
- Use NET-SNMP on target platforms if supported and enable resource collection. Java program can then query the SNMP agent to collect resource usage. You would require a library to talk with SNMP agents. You can SNMP4J or AdventNet for this purpose.

Comment: please can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Im just a Trainee but my solution would be to Write a Server socket and run it on the servers.
Than open a connection over a Client socket and ask for information.

Than i would simpel return the Used Mb or simple convert it to a % Value.

Anyway i would prefer to use a existing and tested solution.

EDIT:

Here a Tutorial on how to get your free , Max and Used RAM.
http://crunchify.com/java-runtime-get-free-used-and-total-memory-in-java/

EDIT2: 
Here the code of my Idear:

Server Part:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    try {
        ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(6969);
        Socket socket = sSocket.accept(); 
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


        String str1 = "";

        //Add Varaibles you want to return
        double ram = 15.0;

        while (!str1.equals("stop")) {
            str1=dis.readUTF();

            //Return Value you need by param 
            if (str1.equals("getRam")) {
                //Add Your calculation here
                dout.writeUTF(String.valueOf(ram));
                dout.flush();   
            }
            else if(str1.equals("stop")){
                dout.writeUTF("stop");
                dout.flush();   
            }
            else {
                dout.writeUTF("Unknown Command");
                dout.flush();
            }


        }
        sSocket.close();
        socket.close();
        dis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }
}
```

Client part:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String serverIp = "localhost";
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverIp, 6969);
            DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dOut= new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            String str = "";
            String str2 = "";


                dOut.writeUTF("getRam");

                //for manual param transmitting 
                //str = br.readLine();
                //dOut.writeUTF(str);
                dOut.flush();
                str2=dIn.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Server response:" + str2);
                br.readLine();



        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);

        }

    }

}
```

I hope that helps you.
Anyway i dont think you can get data without connecting or have a connection to your server.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is i want a simple code native because i will use junit after to do my test

Comment: But what is your connection to the Server?